# List<T> Ordering

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5

I have an issue, I am allowing a user to select the criterea for ordering a List

Lets say my list is called

```
List<Cars> AllCars = new List<Cars>;
allCars = //call the database and get all the cars
```

I now want to order this list

```
allCars.orderBy(registrationDate)
```

I understand the above doesn't work but i haven't anyidea what i should be putting in the brackets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
allCars.OrderBy(c => c.RegistrationDate);
```

Comment: thanks for the speedy reply, however it does not work c=>c. gives me equals,getHash,toString and something else

Comment: allCars must be of type "T" and "registrationDate" must be this types field.

Comment: Since allCars is a list of `Cars`, the `Cars` type must have a public RegistrationDate property or field to orderby.

Comment: Me being silly, My Cars class had the properties hidden so i couldn't see them. It's working now cheers for the heads up Restuta

Answer (score 1):

> I understand the above doesn't work but i haven't anyidea what i should be putting in the brackets.

The declaration of `Enumerable.OrderBy` is

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector
)
```

and, as it's an extension method it can be invoked as

```
source.OrderBy(keySelector).
```

Your `List<Car>` is playing the role of `source` as `List<T> : IEnumerable<T>`. The second parameter is the more interesting one and the one that you are confused by. It's declared as being of type

```
Func<TSource, TKey>
```

This means that it is a delegate that eats instances of `TSource` (in your case `Car`) and returns an instance of `TKey`; it's up to you to decide what `TKey` is. You have stated that you want to order by `Car.registrationDate` so it sounds like `TKey` is `DateTime`. Now, how do we get one of these delegates?

In the old days we could say

```
DateTime GetRegistrationDate(Car car) {
    return car.registrationDate;
}
```

and use `OrderBy` like so:

```
allCars.OrderBy(GetRegistrationDate).
```

In C# 2.0 we gained the ability to use anonymous delegates; these are delegates that don't have a name and are defined in-place.

```
allCars.OrderBy(delegate(Car car) { return car.registrationDate; });
```

Then, in C# 3.0 we gained the ability to use lambda expressions which are very special anonymous delegates with a compact notation

```
allCars.OrderBy(car => car.registrationDate);
```

Here, `c => c.registrationDate` is the lambda expression and it represents a `Func<Car, DateTime>` than can be used the second parameter in `Enumerable.OrderBy`.

> `allCars.orderBy(registrationDate)`

The reason this doesn't work is because `registrationDate` is not a delegate. In fact, without any context at all `registrationDate` is meaningless to the compiler. It doesn't know if you mean `Car.registrationDate` or maybe you mean `ConferenceAttendee.registrationDate` or who knows what. This is why you must give additional context to the compiler and tell it that you want the property `Car.registrationDate`. To do this, you use a delegate in one of the three ways mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation I think i am going to do some more research in to lambada expressions they seem to look straight forward enough